# In hex, how do you know when you've reached the end of a file?

Tags: mp3, hex

When you are reading a physical drive, searching for a mp3 signature (494433), and once you've found that signature; how do you know when you've reached the end of that mp3 file? Is there a signature I am looking for? Do I attempt to find another type of signature?

Comment: It depends on the low-level details of how the file system is laid out.  It's not unusual for a single file to be broken up in chunks, rather than occupying a contiguous set of disk blocks.  And there's generally not going to be any kind of "end of file" marker you can search for.

Comment: Where could I go to get started?

Comment: You'd probably want to start with some introductory material about disk drives and filesystems in general (say, the Wikipedia pages), then look for specific documentation about the type of filesystem used on the drive you're analyzing.  This is not going to be an easy project for a beginner.

Comment: No one stop book I take it ;p

Answer (score 0):

0x49 0x44 0x33 are numeric encodings for the ASCII characters ID3, indicating the beginning of a 2.x ID3 tag.  Tags are typically at the beginning of an mp3 file.  The mp3 data itself consists of a series of frames after the ID3 tag.  There's no magic value indicating EOF, you just run out of frames.  Also, ID3 version 1 tags are typically at the end of an mp3 file and are 128 bytes in size.  They can be found looking 128 bytes from EOF, for the ASCII characters TAG.

See: http://id3.org/Developer_Information

See: http://www.mp3-tech.org/programmer/frame_header.html

It's certainly easier to read any kind of data using the file system driver for the file system on the drive you're reading.  Either way (fs driver vs. no fs driver) you need to know which file system is implemented if you're going to traverse files on the drive.